# Extending react custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react component called editPhoto.js it has a onDeleteFile method that I want to override when I extend it. The problem is editPhoto.js is connected to a redux store. Is inheritance the wrong approach here ? Or how would I go about extending and overriding the EditPhoto onDeleteFile and save methods ?

**UPDATE:** 11-1

**editPhoto.js** does all the same functionality that editBlog needs to do. So in OOP terms this is a classic case for inheritance by extending editPhoto with editBlog so editBlog inherits all of editPhoto's functions and properties. With inheritance I could also override two methods that editBlog uses differently from editPhoto. The **save** and **onDeleteFile** functions.

Here is how both those functions are used differently.

**save() method should call a different action:**

```
save(){

   all the same (save) method code in editPhoto goes here....

   // this.props.editPhoto(formData, this.props.history) should be changed to
   this.props.editBlog(formData, this.props.history).

}
```

**onDeleteFile() method should call a different action:**

```
onDeleteFile(){

   all the same (onDeleteFile) method code in editPhoto goes here....

   // this.props.editBlog(this.state.id, this.props.history) should be changed to
   this.props.deletePhoto(this.state.id, this.props.history)

}
```

Thats the only two changes in the code which seems crazy to have to duplicate 112 lines of code for just 2 lines to be changed.
Id' also like to know how you would override a method using composition but its not necessary in this case (maybe best for another post).

If there is a way of doing this with composition I'm totally open to not using inheritance as it wont inherit when using the Redux connect in EditPhoto.

END OF UPDATE 11-1 -------------------------------

See all code below trying to do the same thing in inheritance.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import EditPhoto from './editPhoto';

export default class EditBlog extends EditPhoto{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  // override original EditPhoto
  onDeleteFile(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("DeleteBlog : onDeleteFile");
    this.props.deleteBlog(this.state.id, this.props.history)
  }

 save( event ){
   event.preventDefault();
   const formData .....
   // call different action for editBlog(formData, this.props.history);
 }

}
```

Here is my editPhoto.js code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import FieldEditor from '../../components/admin/fieldEditor';
import DropzoneArea from '../../components/admin/dropzoneArea';
import {editPhoto, deletePhoto} from '../../actions/index';

import style from '../../../styles/admin/editPhoto.scss';

class EditPhoto extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onUpdateState = this.onUpdateState.bind(this);
    this.handleDrop = this.handleDrop.bind(this);
    this.save = this.save.bind(this);
    this.onDeleteFile = this.onDeleteFile.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      fieldEdits:'',
      preview:'',
      file:'',
      id:''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    if(this.props.location.state)
    this.setState({
      preview: this.props.location.state.photo.photo,
      fieldEdits: this.props.location.state.photo,
      id: this.props.location.state.photo._id
    })
  }

  onUpdateState(fieldEdits){
    this.setState({fieldEdits});
  }

  handleDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles){
    acceptedFiles.forEach( (file, index) => {
       const reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = ( event ) => {
          const img = event.target.result;
          this.setState({preview:img, file});
       };
       reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted');
       reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed');

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });
  }

  onDeleteFile(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.deletePhoto(this.state.id, this.props.history);
  }

  save( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = document.forms.namedItem("photoEditUpload");
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    if(this.state.file.name){
      formData.append('photos', this.state.file, this.state.file.name);
    }

    formData.append('id', this.state.id);

    // for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    //     console.log(pair[0]+ ' = ' + pair[1]);
    // }

    this.props.editPhoto(formData, this.props.history);
  }

  render(){
    if(!this.props.location.state){
      // TO DO : ADD IN A ERROR COMPONENT FOR THIS.
      return <div>No photo to edit. GO BACK !</div>
    }
    return(
      <div id="edit-photo" className='container'>
        <form onSubmit={this.save} ref='form' role="save" encType="multipart/form-data" name="photoEditUpload" method="post">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="photo-container col-sm-8">
              <img src={this.state.preview} className="edit-photo"></img>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-4">
              <div>
                <Dropzone onDrop={this.handleDrop} multiple={false} accept="image/jpeg" className="dropzone">
                  <DropzoneArea />
                </Dropzone>
              </div>
              <div className="delete-container">
                <button onClick={this.onDeleteFile} className='btn btn-primary' type='button'>Delete</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <FieldEditor callback={this.onUpdateState} {...this.state.fieldEdits} />
          <div className="button-container">
            <button className='btn btn-primary btn-save' type='submit'>Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, {editPhoto, deletePhoto})(EditPhoto);
```

---

**NOTE:**
Here is a stripped down version in jsfiddle showing the issue after palsrealm suggested passing the context so the store would not be undefined. 
https://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/jzprkx96/31/

Comment: Are you asking how to connect to your Redux store in the extended component?  You should be able to connect like any other component.  Inheritance seems like a good idea in your case.

Comment: Any chance of an example because I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined"

Comment: `import {connect} from 'react-redux'; export default connect()(EditBlog);` ?

Comment: As I said I get an error "connect.js:130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined
    at EditBlog.Connect (connect.js:130)
    at new EditBlog (editBlog.js:33)"

Comment: I see, hmmm.  You could just duplicate `EditPhoto` and rename it with the modifications you need.  Right?

Comment: Right but I have a few components like this and its getting ridiculous to have to keep duplicating code when all I need to do is override 2 methods. Seems pretty bad that I can't extend something that is connected to a Redux store.

Comment: Not sure why its saying undefined store for EditBlog and not EditPhoto.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are extending the component created by

```
export default connect(null, {editPhoto, deletePhoto})(EditPhoto);
```

If you look into the `react-redux` documentation, you can see that `connect` returns the `Connect` component, [which extends React.Component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/4c2670dc11cc067ef106f6c527e6e8b9d47f8af8/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L115).

When you declare

```
export default class EditBlog extends EditPhoto {
```

it might look like you are extending `class EditPhoto` but you're actually extending `Connect`. `Connect` wraps `EditPhoto` by composition and has no idea what `EditPhoto`'s methods and properties are. There is no inheritance chain to help you out. `Connect` is also getting pissed off and throwing errors because it doesn't expect to get used like this.

The naming of your import at `import EditPhoto from './editPhoto';` is misleading.

If you want to extend the class `EditPhoto`, you need to export the class itself

```
export class EditPhoto extends Component {
```

and import that in your `EditBlog` module

```
import {EditPhoto} from './editPhoto';

export default class EditBlog extends EditPhoto {
```

BUT - I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Inheritance is an antipattern in React. Check out [the React docs on Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.

So... I would step back and try to solve the problem again with composition.

**Update - Composition Example**

Based on the extra detail you give in your update, I would probably start with a generic `EditAsset` component something like...

```
class EditAsset extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
      deleteAsset: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      updateAsset: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      ...any other asset-specific props
    }

    handleDelete = () => {
      ...do generic stuff...
      this.props.deleteAsset(id, whatever, whatever)
    }

    handleSave = () => {
      ...do generic stuff...
      this.props.updateAsset(id, whatever, whatever)
    }

    render = () => {
      ...all your generic render stuff...
    }

}
```

Then you can use redux `connect` to compose different components to deal with specific asset types. e.g.

```
import {EditAsset} from './path/to/EditAsset';
import {deletePhoto, updatePhoto, deleteBlog, editBlog} from './path/to/actions';

export const EditPhoto = connect(
   undefined,
   dispatch => ({
       deleteAsset: (...args) => dispatch(deletePhoto(...args)),
       updateAsset: (...args) => dispatch(updatePhoto(...args)),
   })
)(EditAsset);

export const EditBlog = connect(
   undefined,
   dispatch => ({
       deleteAsset: (...args) => dispatch(deleteBlog(...args)),
       updateAsset: (...args) => dispatch(updateBlog(...args)),
   })
)(EditAsset);
```

So, you write the generic component once and use composition to create one, two, one thousand specific components with appropriate data and methods passed down as props.

In this example we are just passing down two action dispatchers but you could obviously use `mapStateToProps` to pass down whatever specific data you need.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks Marc no you do not sound like a dick at all. I read the same article you sent before I posted thats why I said in my post "Is inheritance the wrong approach here?" All of my code is in the post I created. All i'm trying to do is extend from editPhoto and override 2 methods onDeleteFile and save. The issue here is the connection to the store. I'm happy to use composition if thats what react likes better but I just don;t fully understand it when it comes to other HOC like connect redux. I see plenty of examples for composition but not much on how to handle already connected components.

Comment: I'll try and put together a stripped down version of the code for you. Would that help. I mean it will still be the same code as above just removing most of the html and the dropzone stuff.

Comment: @ericb OK dude. Have changed my answer to identify your specific problem but have retained the general advice against inheritance :)

Comment: Thanks Marc for the explanation. Now I get why its happening but not how to fix it. I've made a simplified version on jsfiddle showing the setup stripped down. https://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/jzprkx96/31/  As I have said in my first comment I only see composition examples without using Redux. Bring Redux into the fold and I have no idea how to do the composition. Do you have an example ? Or maybe you can update my jsfiddle using composition.

Comment: I can't seem to get your idea of exporting the class itself along with the connect to work. It will only work if I export the class without the redux connect which is defeating the purpose of using redux. You suggested  composition with no example of how composition would work. Can you please explain ?

Comment: OK. Not being able to extend redux connected components does not defeat the purpose of redux. Redux uses composition return connected components. The term 'connected components' is kind of misleading because the connected component is not the component you started out with (in your case EditPhoto), it is a totally new component. So - you can't expect to try to extend it and inherit the stuff that lives on your original component. If you really want to use inheritance, you need to write your components then wrap each of them with redux connect in order to connect them to the store...

Comment: ...BUT let's not carry on down that road. Let's solve this with connect and composition. I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve with this pattern or what duplication you are trying to avoid. If you want to give a bit more information on what you want each of these components to do and what data they need from the store perhaps I can help more.

Comment: Thanks Marc I appreciate the help and I totally agree about the inheritance road. I’d much prefer to see how to do it with composition. I edited the original post with a section called UPDATE: 11-1. This hopefully explains what I need to do more clearly.

Comment: Have updated with an example of composition. Let me know if you need more detail/explanation with that.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Yes more detailed explanation would help. I have a lot of questions here. I guess first I see connect is connecting the store to EditAsset instead of each of the components like I have currently. Right ? Next question does EditAsset have all the code like onUpdateState, handleDrop ...... and so on, that is currently in EditPhoto ? Also is EditPhoto and EditBlog all one file now and are these the dumb components that I render to show on the page. I guess because I can't see it working I have so many questions.

Comment: What are the ...args I'm dispatching to EditAsset from editPhoto using    dispatch => ({
       deleteAsset: (...args) => dispatch(deletePhoto(...args)),
       updateAsset: (...args) => dispatch(updatePhoto(...args)),
   })

Comment: Whats rendered inside EditAsset ? Is EditPhoto a class or just meant to be what you wrote only for to connect to the store. Does this get a render and if so what is rendered ? Sorry for all the questions but not sure how this all works what has to be called to render what ? But this does look exciting and happy to see how it all works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158086/discussion-between-marc-davies-and-ericb).

Answer (score 1):

The `store` is passed around in `Redux` using the `context`, which is then connected to the class using the `connect` HOC. So, if you want your `EditBlog` component to have access to the `store` you need to pass the `context` in the `constructor`.

```
constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
  }
```

The call to `super` in the constructor creates the `this` keyword for the class. When you pass the context in the constructor and then to the super, the context is also used to create the `this` for the class along with the props. This will give access to the `store` to the `EditBlog` class.

More information at : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Example code : https://codesandbox.io/s/1qrnmqror3

**Edit 11/1**: As described in [@MarcDavies answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032288/2345964) there is no inheritance chain to help you achieve what you are trying to do. Instead you should use composition. To use composition you can redesign your components such that the parts that are common are in one component and the parts that change are in  different components.

I do not know enough about your components to make an informed design but from what I could get from your update, you are going to vary the functionality of the delete button based on whether it is a photo or a blog. To do that you can create a `DeletePhoto` button and a `DeleteBlog` button which would get the common delete functionality as `props`. The common parent component would know whether it is a blog or a photo and render the appropriate button accordingly.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you for that clarification. Now that I'm passing context to the parent how can I override the onDeleteFile. I thought by just adding the same method to my child (EditBlog) it would override it. But when I click on the delete button it is calling the onDeleteFile method inside parent (EditPhoto) instead of the overridden onDeleteFile method inside child (EditBlog). <button onClick={this.onDeleteFile}> should call the onDeleteFile method in the extended child object.

Comment: So in parent (EditPhoto.js) when I don't use export default connect(null, {editPhoto, deletePhoto})(EditPhoto); and just export the class without connect then calling <button onClick={this.onDeleteFile}> will call the onDeleteFile method inside child (EditBlog.js). Which is what it should do. Why would it not do the same when connect is used in EditPhoto ?

Comment: Looks like "this" in EditPhoto.js is referencing EditPhoto when using export default connect but when just exporting the class its referencing EditBlog when extended. Anyone know a way to get around this so that when I use export default connect(null, {editPhoto, deletePhoto})(EditPhoto); and extend EditPhoto with EditBlog it references EditBlog with "this"

Comment: jsfiddle showing the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/jzprkx96/31/

Comment: updated answer based on your update and your discussion with @Marc Davies